# What AVCaptureDevice does Camera.app use?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have a camera in my app. It's been carefully implemented following a lot of documentation, but it still has a major annoyance; the field of view is significantly smaller than the stock camera app. Here's two screenshots taken at approx the same distance for reference. My app is on the right, showing the entire preview stream from the camera.

[image]

Apple docs suggest using `AVCaptureDevice.default` or `AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession`, and my app uses the former;

```
AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
```

I've tried many of the different capture devices, and none of them give me the same wide preview as the stock Camera app.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.builtInUltraWideCamera`? You have to use `DiscoverySession` according to docs: _You can only discover this device type using an AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession_.

Comment: did my solution work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you need to expand the view bounds in your example to compare like for like.

Then you'll notice that in your left image, the capture mode is set to "PHOTO", not "VIDEO". If you switch tabs to the "VIDEO" mode in Camera.app you'll see that the zoom for both sessions is the same.

To enable this is a minor change:

```
let session = AVCaptureSession()
session.beginConfiguration()
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
```

Usually, I would caution against using the Photo preset however you are capturing photos.. so reduced video stabilisation is tolerable. There is also a consideration of video quality as the `.hd1920x1080` session preset produces higher resolution video and also is optimised for video.

```
let session = AVCaptureSession()
session.beginConfiguration()
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

// Add a video input
guard session.canAddInput(deviceInput) else {
  print("Couldn't add device input")
  return
}
session.addInput(deviceInput) 

session.startRunning()
```

`DiscoverySession` approach could replace this if you want to have a cleaner solution for backup device option in case wide angle is not available. But with default, get the device input as follows:

```
guard let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back) else {
  print("Couldn't find wide angle camera")
  return
}

guard let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice) else {
  print("Could not create video device input.")
  return
}
```

If you're using `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` it's better to use input device dimensions for the view to avoid resizing with `previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect` even though it works compared to `previewLayer.videoGravity = .resize` (it has performance overheads).

Comment: Sorry, looks great. Went on vacation. Will try!

Comment: It worked! I went in another direction with the product, but thank you for this thorough answer.

Comment: videoGravity = .resize is brilliant